# Adding device to Developer Profile managed By Xcode

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile, iphone-developer-program

I'm trying to add a device to my developer profile. But this profile is managed by Xcode. I do not have the device on hand. I only have the UDID. I'm running Xcode 4.6. Can anyone help me?

Regards,
EZFrag

Answer (score 1):

I ended up revoking the Certificate and issuing a new one. The developer program can be such a hassle sometimes. It's going to be funny though :P Monday morning about +30 devs won't be able to run nothing